# Mathematical Logic: binary connector * symbol

Tags: logic, binary

I'm studying Mathematical Logic and I am stuck on this problem.

I've been understanding everything, but I'm stuck on this exercise, because I never seen this symbol in classes, needer on the internet, and I can't find it anywhere.

I am Portuguese (from Portugal), so I'm going to do my best to translate:

---

1. In the exercise they are asking me to construct a Truth Table, "
   considering the binary connective * ";
2. They give me the truth table of **(P * Q)**;
3. They also give me the propositional " **(p^q) * (p <=> q) => (p*q) v ~p** ", from which I need to make the Truth Table as I said in 1.

**What is the binary connective *?**

Can someone, please, explain me or give me a link?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The answer lies in the given truth table, which you forgot to show.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I thought that * was some kind of connector. I see the answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what the truth table you are given consists of. For instance, if the truth table looks like
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
p &\quad q\quad & p * q\\
T &\quad T\quad & T\\
T &\quad F\quad & F\\
F &\quad T\quad & T\\
F &\quad F\quad & T
\end{eqnarray*}$$
then $*$ is the conditional, $\to$.

Comment: It's worth noting that it could just as easily be none of the standard logical connectives (I assume it probably is not).

Comment: @SpencerWhitehead All 16 of them are either standard, or the converse of standard, or are degenerate in some way...

Comment: The truth table for (P * Q) is P(FFVV), Q(FVFV), P*Q(VVVF). So basically they are sying that * = v (or/disjunction), right? Edit: No, it's not a disjunction...

Comment: Of course; my use of 'standard' is probably not optimal. Personally, in my first logic course, I learned $\land, \lor, \implies$ for binary connectives, so I suppose I meant more along the lines of 'does not have to match up with one of these'

Comment: @shivayl The point is that * does not have to be any of the connectives you already know ... as long as its truth-table is defined in 2, you can work out the truth-table for the statement in 3

Comment: @Bram28 Got it! Thank you, I didn't think on that